# turnkey linux (LAMP stack edition) 16.1 - how to dd entire partition to USB via terminal?

Tags: debian, dd

I have it set up so I can access the shell directly from a computer on this local area network just by typing in its local IP. Is there a way to back up the entire disk (while using the operating system of that disk) to a USB flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, however the contained file systems will have errors or inconsistencies because the file system (if mounted read/write) will by dynamically changing. You can reduce the incidence of these errors using 'sync' however this cannot prevent all errors. Most of these errors will be trivial (missing data blocks in recently written files), but some could be severe. Tools such as 'fsck' are likely to be able to make the copy usable as an imperfect copy.

Comment: I see. So what would you recommend? Booting from UBCD and doing it that way?